# Javascript code working in IE11 but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

we are experiencing a strange problem with IE11/Chrome here. We have this little code:

```
divFrmPost = document.getElementById('divFormPost'); 
divFrmPost.innerHTML = '<form name="formPost" method="post" \ action="http://someurl/servlet/myapp"> \    
    <input type="hidden" id="cd_user" name="cd_user" value="John Doe"> \    
    <input type="hidden" id="cod_user" name="cod_user" value="5013"> \    
    <input type="hidden" id="login" name="login" value="jdoe"> \    
    <input type="hidden" id="pwd" name="pwd" value="123456"> \    
    <input type="hidden" id="profile" name="profile" value="12"> \   
    <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="128"> \
</form>'; 
frmPost = document.getElementById('formPost');
frmPost.submit();
```

When we run it in IE11, the form is processed okay, but when we run it in Chrome (v44), it do nothing, and in the console we have this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null`

We understand the problem must be the last hidden field, with no id/name, but why does it work in IE11 and don't work in Chrome?

**EDIT**: In the original code the innerHTML construction is a single line, I edited it for better reading, but I forgot to put the backslashes.

**EDIT2**: Please, let's avoid comment war...

Comment: I don't see any id `formPost` so you can't expect `document.getElementById('formPost')` to return something. it might work in IE because of `name="formPost"` and variable `formPost` (typo) might already hold this form

Comment: document.formPost.submit(); should work.

Comment: Perhaps Chrome is fussier about what it accepts. Perhaps it is just because it can't find the element, as you have not specified the ID in the form tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Make it work

First of all we must edit the code to make it work:
As others said you are looking for id but on the form there's only name set and Chrome and other real browsers doesn't like it.

```js
divFrmPost = document.getElementById('divFormPost');
divFrmPost.innerHTML = '<form id="formPost" method="post" action="http://someurl/servlet/myapp">'    
   + '<input type="hidden" id="cd_user" name="cd_user" value="John Doe">'    
   + '<input type="hidden" id="cod_user" name="cod_user" value="5013">'    
   + '<input type="hidden" id="login" name="login" value="jdoe">'    
   + '<input type="hidden" id="pwd" name="pwd" value="123456">'    
   + '<input type="hidden" id="profile" name="profile" value="12">'    
   + '<input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="128">'
+'</form>';
frmPost = document.getElementById('formPost');
frmPost.submit();
```

```html
<div id="divFormPost"></div>
```

#### Multiline string

To concatenate a string on multiple lines you should use +

#### Why it works on IE?

Here the answer

> getElementById method < IE 8
>
> Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID or NAME attribute.

From [MSDN Microsoft getElementById method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx)

Maybe it's working for you on IE 11 because of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx), if you don't define `<!DOCTYPE>` IE enables Quirks mode

> Quirks mode emphasizes compatibility over standards compliance by supporting behavior found in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks SharpEdge! Why does it work in IE11 though? Could be IE11 interpret *name* as *id* when you just provide the *id*, and Chrome does not?

Comment: In IE7 and previous, getElementById also return objects with name=id, as we can see here: http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t10

Comment: Microsoft is famous for not respecting their own rules so don't be surprised, there are plenty of questions on SO about this argument.

Comment: I'm not sure the original code works on IE, i'm using linux so i can't try it. Following the MSDN API Reference it should not work.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
name="formPost"
```

to

```
id="formPost"
```

or use

```
getElementsByName();
```

Your code will be

```
 divFrmPost = document.getElementById('divFormPost'); 
divFrmPost.innerHTML = '<form id="formPost" method="post" action="http://someurl/servlet/myapp">    
    <input type="hidden" id="cd_user" name="cd_user" value="John Doe">    
    <input type="hidden" id="cod_user" name="cod_user" value="5013">    
    <input type="hidden" id="login" name="login" value="jdoe">    
    <input type="hidden" id="pwd" name="pwd" value="123456">    
    <input type="hidden" id="profile" name="profile" value="12">    
    <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="128">
</form>'; 
frmPost = document.getElementById('formPost');
frmPost.submit();
```

Comment: Because its IE. It takes name as id. But normal browsers use Id and name

Comment: In some way. The case here is that you should use id

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You can't split a string in multiple lines via a conventional string notation. I changed it to a [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). You can add `+` at the end of lines for IE compatibility.
2. You form doesn't have the ID. So I added it. `<form id="formPost" name="formPost" ...`

Here is the working code:

```
        divFrmPost = document.getElementById('divFormPost'); 
        divFrmPost.innerHTML = `<form id="formPost" name="formPost" method="post" action="http://someurl/servlet/myapp">;    
            <input type="hidden" id="cd_user" name="cd_user" value="John Doe">    
            <input type="hidden" id="cod_user" name="cod_user" value="5013">    
            <input type="hidden" id="login" name="login" value="jdoe">    
            <input type="hidden" id="pwd" name="pwd" value="123456">    
            <input type="hidden" id="profile" name="profile" value="12">    
            <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="128">
        </form>`; 
        frmPost = document.getElementById('formPost');
        frmPost.submit();
```

Comment: There is no irony. I have very clearly stated that template strings doesn't support IE and has provided an alternative to that.

Comment: Please type this in your console: 

`var wisdom = 'Now I see' + 
' where I have got wrong';`

Comment: @CharlieH then you need to add quotes to close/open strings. but btw OP might already do this on one line (better visibility in the post), that's why he did not escaped the string.

Comment: Your logic is wrong buddy! He said the snip works in IE even without the id in the form. So it was clear that this snip is not about his real issue. Everyone answered, included me, pointing both the string and id. You started whining even without an answer. Try this `alert("some goes without saying... like common sense")`

Comment: Thank you Charlie H! We knew the problem was in the id/name, but we were really interested in why it was working on IE11 and not in Chrome. it turns out it was the way IE7 and previous processes the getElementByID function (the app in question runs in iE7 compatibility mode). And please do not answer that other guy comments: it's sad, but Stack Overflow today is polluted by pseudo-helpers that needs to pick on every little thing instead of focus on the real question... I bet the downvote I had in this question came from him... ;-)

Comment: @tcbrazil - You are welcome. Great you solved the issue and if I could help in some degree. I talked about the Temple Strings because its a new feature and someone could learn.